# db2 dynamic cursor declaration

Tags: sql, plsql, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure, but I get this error

> Expected tokens may include:  "".  LINE NUMBER=17.  SQLSTATE=42601

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FETCH_EMP_SP(IN V_EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),IN V_EMP_DEPT VARCHAR(100))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE p_query_string  VARCHAR(100);
IF ((V_EMP_NAME IS NOT NULL) AND (V_EMP_DEPT IS NOT NULL)) THEN
    SET p_query_string = 'emp_name ='||V_EMP_NAME||' AND emp_dept='||V_EMP_DEPT||' WITH UR';
ELSEIF(V_EMP_DEPT IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SET p_query_string = ' AND emp_dept='||V_EMP_DEPT||' WITH UR';
ELSE
    SET p_query_string = ' WITH UR';
END IF;

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR SELECT emp_name,emp_no,emp_dept,emp_location from employee where status=1 p_query_string;
OPEN C1;
END@
```

should be executed successfully

Answer (score 4):

Declarations and statements can’t follow in arbitrary order in a [Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html)

Cursor declarations must follow the variables declarations and must be followed by the SQL procedure statements.

So, place the cursor declaration after the variable declaration.

Moreover, there is a number of other errors in your code. Should be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FETCH_EMP_SP(IN V_EMP_NAME VARCHAR(100),IN V_EMP_DEPT VARCHAR(100))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE p_query_string  VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR S1;

IF ((V_EMP_NAME IS NOT NULL) AND (V_EMP_DEPT IS NOT NULL)) THEN
    SET p_query_string = ' AND emp_name ='''||V_EMP_NAME||''' AND emp_dept='''||V_EMP_DEPT||''' WITH UR';
ELSEIF(V_EMP_DEPT IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SET p_query_string = ' AND emp_dept='''||V_EMP_DEPT||''' WITH UR';
ELSE
    SET p_query_string = ' WITH UR';
END IF;

SET p_query_string='SELECT emp_name,emp_no,emp_dept,emp_location from employee where status=1 '||p_query_string;
PREPARE S1 FROM p_query_string;
OPEN C1;
END@
```

String constants in the query text must be wrapped in single quotes. Don't do this if `emp_dept` is a numeric column.